Azure DevOps - Columns for Groups
Can I only have three groups here? I'm looking for a solution, because I should have columns like:
Data Início, Data Final, Data Conclusão, Responsável and Prazo. But as far as I'm concerned, DevOps only allows me to have three groups. Does anyone here can help me?
I tried finding a plug-in and reading other topics, but nothing seemed to work.
Thank you!

I am afraid that there is no such method can increase the columns for the groups in one work item layout page.
Currently, Azure DevOps only supports three columns for the groups in one Work item layout page.

Refer to this doc: Layout and resizing

The web form layout is organized into three columns. If you only add groups and fields to the first two columns, then the layout reflects a two-column layout. Likewise, if you only add groups and fields to the first column, then the layout reflects a one-column layout.

For a workaround, you can add two pages in the work item layout page. And you can split multiple column names into two groups and put them in two Pages.
For example:


I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature

Thank you so much, Kevin! I appreciate your answer. I'll see how it goes splitting it into two pages as you mentioned.
